# Set cron schedule from properties file rather than hard coding it and still avoid Attribute value must be constant

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-scheduled

I'm using SchedulerLock to create a schedule in my Spring Boot application. Currently the schedule is hard coded to run every 3 hours:

```
private final String everyThreeHours = "0 0 */3 * * *";

@Scheduled(cron = everyThreeHours)
public void runCleanupSchedule() throws IOException {
    ...
}
```

I'd like to make `everyThreeHours` dynamic so I can have different schedules in the properties file for each environment. Unfortunately when I put this in the properties file I get `Attribute value must be constant`. Is there any way I can set this in my properties rather than having it hard coded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${scheduled.everyThreeHours}")
public void runCleanupSchedule() throws IOException {
    ...
}
```

in your **application.properties** add **scheduled.everyThreeHours**

```
scheduled.everyThreeHours=0 0 */3 * * *
```

and you can change the value for each environment properties file